# Load data from flat file into oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, import, oracle-sql-developer

I created a new database, then created a table "users". Now, I'm trying to load data to this table from a flat file called 'users.tbl', that has some records  with the following format:

```
1|john|email@email.email|active
```

I'm using SQL Developer for this, i tried the following commands.

```
load data infile `"C:\path" 
insert into table users 
fields terminated by "|" 
lines terminated by "\r\n";
```

But the data is not loaded and no errors are shown. Do you see why its not working? Or How can i load the data in the flat file to Oracle table?

Comment: This could be helpful [LOAD DATA INFILE equivalent in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953110/load-data-infile-equivalent-in-oracle)

Comment: Can you provide some more details?  What exactly have you done?  Where is your file, on the client or on the server?  What version of SQL Developer?

Comment: You should use a hex editor to see if you have both a line feed and a carriage return. It's possible that the file only has a line feed. Also you can try creating an external table to read the data. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question you have data in the flat file and you want to access it or can load to another table. Basically you are talking about **external tables**. You want to read more on it. Here is the Oracle Documentation link: [External Tables Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm).

Here is the example how I loaded your data into my external table and created another table from it.

```
[oracle@testsrv1 Desktop]$ cat user.tbl 
 1|john|email@email.com|active
[oracle@testsrv1 Desktop]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Mar 3 06:45:26 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create user user1 identified by user1;

User created.

SQL> create directory user_dir as '/home/oracle/Desktop';

Directory created.


SQL> grant resource, connect to user1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant read, write on directory user_dir to user1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn user1/user1
Connected.

SQL> create table user_load(user_id number, name varchar2(20), email varchar2(50), status varchar2(10))
organization external
(default directory user_dir
access parameters
(fields terminated by '|')
location('user.tbl')
);   

Table created.

SQL> select * from user_load;

   USER_ID NAME          EMAIL                  STATUS
---------- ----------   -------------------    ----------
     1 john         email@email.com        active


SQL> create table final as select * from user_load;

Table created

SQL> select * from final;

   USER_ID NAME          EMAIL                  STATUS
---------- ----------   -------------------    ----------
     1 john         email@email.com        active
```